# Bluetooth LE: undocumented error code 19

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, android-5.0-lollipop, android-bluetooth

My Android app uses BLE APIs, and one of these APIs, *BluetoothGattCallback.onConnectionStateChange()*, receives an undocumented error code 19. I'm using Nexus 9.

Did anybody ever see this error code before? Like I mentioned above, this is undocumented in the Android API reference, and I don't know what to do about it.

P.S.

I searched issue tickets at [Android issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list) also, and found that developers encounter undocumented, BLE-related error codes often. Hmm, this is grim.

Comment: The undocumented error code can mainly be found inside a C header file inside Android source code. Didn't have the source in hand so cannot tell you the exact file though.

Comment: I have added a ticket in issue tracker more than a year ago requesting documentation for the undocumented error codes, but still no response until now.

Comment: @reTs  can you post the link to that issue? I wanna star it.